# Is there a continuous bijection from $\mathbb{Q}$ to $\mathbb{Q^*}$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, elementary-set-theory

I am trying to find an explicit function but I don't know if that is even possible.
Thanks

Comment: What is the definition of $\mathbb{Q}^{\ast}$?

Comment: I mean the rationals without 0

Comment: **Hint:** think of irrational numbers.

Comment: is it possible to make it order preserving or not? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start by writing down an explicit bijection from $\Bbb Q\cap(a,b]$ to $\Bbb Q\cap(c,d]$, for any real numbers $a,b$ and rational numbers $c>a$ and $d>b$. Choose decreasing sequences $b = b_0 > b_1 > b_2 > \cdots$ and $d = d_0 > d_1 > d_2 > \cdots$ of rational numbers such that $b_n\to a$ and $d_n\to c$. Then let $f\colon (a,b]\to(c,d]$ be the piecewise linear function joining the points $(b_n,d_n)$, that is:
$$
f(x) = d_n + \frac{d_n-d_{n-1}}{b_n-b_{n-1}} (b_n-x) \quad\text{for } x\in [b_n,b_{n-1}].
$$
Since this line has rational slope, $f$ is a bijection between $\Bbb Q\cap (b_n,b_{n-1}]$ and $\Bbb Q \cap (d_n,d_{n-1}]$. The fact that $f$ is a bijection between $\Bbb Q\cap(a,b]$ to $\Bbb Q\cap(c,d]$ follows from the fact that $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty (b_n,b_{n-1}] = (a,b]$ and $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty (d_n,d_{n-1}] = (c,d]$.

Now for the stated problem: fix an irrational number $y$ and two rational numbers $n < 0 < p$ with $|n|,|p|>|y|$. Use the above process to write down a bijection from $\Bbb Q\cap(0,p]$ to $\Bbb Q\cap(y,p]$, and the same process (multiplied through by $-1$) to write down a bijection from $\Bbb Q\cap[n,0)$ to $\Bbb Q\cap[n,y)$. The union of these two bijectinos with the obvious bijections from $(p,\infty)$ to itself and $(-\infty,n)$ to itself forms a bijection from $\Bbb Q^*$ to $\Bbb Q$.

Answer (score 0):

Any two countable densely ordered sets with no first or last element are order isomorphic. One can build such an order isomorphism using the [Back and Forth Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-and-forth_method) of Cantor.

Comment: thank you for your answer but I wanted to know if it was possible to have an explicit function?

Comment: I think of the Back and Forth Method as explicit, since it can be described algorithmically in terms of an enumeration of the rationals, which can be made explicit. However, certainly the isomorphism so produced is not natural.

Comment: We can probably be more explicit by mapping the negative elements of $\mathbb{Q}^\ast$ to rationals $\lt \sqrt{2}$, and the rest to rationals $\gt \sqrt{2}$.

Comment: ah, thanks, I was trying to find an explicit formula but the bijections I had were not order preserving, that's why I was asking...